# How to prevent Chrome from replacing the URL on a 204?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome seems to have this annoying behavior where if a website returns a 204, instead of reporting anything, it just replaces the current URL in the address bar with the one previously there, if there was one (even if that previous URL was invalid, or returned 204 itself...). Is there any way to force chrome to keep the current URL in the address bar? When testing an endpoint it's annoying to have to keep retyping the URL.